# Prove that matrix $A=c \cdot I$ where $I$ is an identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that $AB=BA$ for all $B \implies A=c \cdot I $ for some $c$ where $I$ is an identity matrix.

Both $A,B\in M_{n \times n}.$ I don't know how attempt proof.

Comment: Quantifiers, please.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: As such, your assertion is false.

Comment: What you want to say is: If $AB = BA$ for EVERY matrix $B$. The "for every" is a quantifier (often written $\forall$ or, "for all").

Comment: The exact problem is : Let $A \in M_{n \times n}$ Show if the only matrix at $M_{n \times n}$ similar to $A$ is $A$ then $A=c \cdot I$

Comment: You want to ask how to prove that $$\forall A\in M_{n\times n}\left(\forall B\in M_{n\times n}(AB=BA)\implies \exists c\in \mathbb C(A=cI_n)\right),$$ but you didn't. Instead you omitted quantifiers which leaves people guessing at what's is being asked. For instance taking $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$ you get a counter-example to a statement that looks like what you wrote.

Comment: Look up the proof of Schur's lemma.

Comment: I meant $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use special matrices. If $E_{h}$ is the matrix having $1$ in place $(h,h)$ and $0$ elsewhere, then $AE_{h}$ is the matrix
$$
\begin{matrix}
[\,0&\dots&0&a_h&0&\dots&0\,]\\
&&&\uparrow\\
&&& \scriptstyle h
\end{matrix}
$$
having all zero columns except for the $h$-th column, which is the $h$-th column of $A$. Similarly, the matrix $E_{h}A$ is the matrix having all zero rows except for the $h$-th row, which is the $h$-th row of $A$.

In particular, $a_{hj}=0$ for $j\ne h$. Since $h$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $A$ is diagonal.

Now consider the matrix $E_{hk}$ that's obtained from the identity by switching the $h$-th row with the $k$-th row (for $h\ne k$). It's easy to show that $E_{hk}$ is the matrix obtained from $A$ by switching the $h$-th row with the $k$-th row. Similarly, $AE_{hk}$ is obtained from $A$ by switching the $h$-th column with the $k$-th column.

Thus, by comparing $E_{1k}A$ with $AE_{1k}$, we conclude that the coefficient in place $(h,h)$ of $A$ is the same as the coefficient in place $(1,1)$.

Therefore all coefficients on the diagonal are equal. Call this common coefficient $c$ and we have proved that $A=cI$.

---

Note that this uses only matrix multiplication where the special matrices used have only coefficients $0$ and $1$, so it holds for matrices over any commutative ring.